# ffmpegを使ってmpeg2tsのデータから画像とklvデータを同時に取得したい

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg

ffmpegでmpeg2tsの動画をストリーミング配信をして、ストリームから画像データとklvデータを同期して取り出したいと思っています。
以下のようにして、画像とklvを別々に取り出すことは可能なのですが、お互いが紐づいた形で取得することはできないでしょうか？
データ取得に関してはffmpegを使わなくても構いません。

ストリーミング配信

```
ffmpeg -re -i DayFlight.mpg -map 0 -c copy -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:5004
```

画像取得

```
ffmpeg -i 'udp://127.0.0.1:5004' -vsync 0 -q:v 2 %d.jpg
```

klvデータ取得

```
ffmpeg -i udp://127.0.0.1:5004 -c copy -map d:0 -f data streamdata.bin
```